# Java compareTo method. The student.compareTo method should return

Tags: java, string, compareto

I am ask to write a student.compareTo method that should return 0 if the first name of the two students and the last name of the two students is the same. It should return a negative value if the student's name would sort lexicographically lower than the one passed in. it should return a positive value if the student's name would sort lexicographically higher that the one passed in.

here is my code so far. For negative value and the positive value should it be a fixed value or should I use the compareTo value?

```
public int compareTo(Student){
int comparison = (this.firstName.compareTo(Student.firstName));
int comparison2 = (this.lastName.compareTo(Student.lastName));

if (comparison == comparison2)
    return 0;
else if ((comparison=0 && comparison2<0) ||(comparison<0 && comparison2=0)
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
}
```

this is another code. I was wondering if I did this correctly

```
public int compareTo(Student){
    String studentinfo=(this.firstName + this.lastName);
String studentinfo2=(s1.firstName + s1.lastName);
int comparison =studentinfo.compareTo(studentinfo2);
return comparison;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is too complicated...

Chain your comparisons; only if the first one returns 0, run the second; if the second returns 0, run the third; etc.

That is, return the first comparison result which is *non* zero, or the last one. Example:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Student other)
{
    int ret = firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
    if (ret != 0) // No need to go further
        return ret;

    // Hypothetic second comparison to do before lastName
    // ret = foo.compareTo(other.foo);
    // if (ret != 0)
    //     return ret;

    // Rinse, repeat...

    // All previous comparisons returned 0, 
    // return the result of the last comparison
    return lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
}
```

---

Guava has a [nice utility class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) for that:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Student other)
{
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(firstName, other.firstName)
        .compare(lastName, other.lastName)
        .result();
}
```